# The conn_id isn't defined in Airflow JenkinsJobTriggerOperator

Tags: jenkins, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I'm trying to trigger a job in Jenkins using an Airflow dag. I tried the following,

```
dag = DAG("test_jenkins", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

job_trigger = JenkinsJobTriggerOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="trigger_job",
    job_name="generate-code-trigger",
    jenkins_connection_id="http://localhost:8080/"  # The connection must be configured first
)

def grab_artifact_from_jenkins(**context):
hook = JenkinsHook("http://localhost:8080/")
jenkins_server = hook.get_jenkins_server()
url = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='trigger_job')
url = url + "code-generator/pom.xml"  # Or any other artifact name
request = Request(url)
response = jenkins_server.jenkins_open(request)
return response  # We store the artifact content in a xcom variable for later use

artifact_grabber = PythonOperator(
    task_id='artifact_grabber',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=grab_artifact_from_jenkins,
    dag=dag)

artifact_grabber.set_upstream(job_trigger)
```

But this gives me an error,

```
The conn_id `http://localhost:8080/` isn't defined
```

This is my first time using `JenkinsJobTriggerOperator`. Also there are no any helpful examples around. How may I avoid this error.

Comment: Have you already set the conection details under admin --> connecctions in airflow web ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding regarding the jenkins_connection_id.

```
jenkins_connection_id="http://localhost:8080/"  # The connection must be configured first
```

You need to create the proper connection to you jenkins server first, through the airflow UI. What you have setup right now is an example string.
It should look something like this:

```
jenkins_connection_id="the_connection_id_name_which_you_gave_through_the_ui"
```

You can read the details here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it works with bash operator.

```
jenkins_iuser_id = Variable.get("jenkins_user_name")
jenkins_pswd = Variable.get("api_token")

cmand_to_exec ='curl -X POST --user ' + jenkins_iuser_id + ':' + jenkins_pswd + ' http://< IP >:8080/job/<JOBNAME>/build '
trigger_cleanup = BashOperator(
        task_id='trigger_jenkins_cleanup_jobs',
        bash_command=cmand_to_exec,
        dag=dag)
trigger_cleanup
```

Comment: ++ Please make sure your inbound rule for the target server is allowing all traffic!